# The Spirit of Christmas

Tags: word, wordplay, knowledge, visual, seasonal

**Alice:** Help, It's almost Christmas but my house is full of spirits!

**Bob:** But isn't that a good thing? Your family is joyful because it's the holiday season and they're excited for Christmas!

**Alice:** No, not that kind of spirit. I mean the kind that possesses you!!

**Bob:** Ahh, you mean the wicked kind! Well, where is it!? We need to catch them, quick!

**Alice:** I can tell which location of the house they're at but can't pinpoint the exact object they're hiding in. There are six of them in total but they're scattered around eight different locations and ten different objects because some of them can split themselves into two and some of them live in pairs:

---

[image]

---

[image]

[image]

---

[image]

---

***Bob:*** *Hmmm, I think I know an expert to call in for this kind of help...*

**Can you help Alice & Bob find all the hidden spirits?**

---

Hint:

> Not sure if Alice & Bob are on the same page here about the so-called "spirits".

Hint II:

> The spirit at the location three
> is rather small and hard to see,
> but a crazy Igloo junk might help thee.
> Now, complete it with the nearest ____.

Hint III:

> You should focus on the ***name of the objects***.

Hint IV:

> Possess the **he**ad, the ta**il**, the (**whole**) b**od**y.
> These spirits are lexically tricky!
> Why we must rid of them, you ask me?
> Because Christmas is the time for family,
> "spirits" are certainly not allowed!

Addendum:

> ⬤, ⬤ | $◖\ ◗$, $◖\ ◗$ | $◖◖ ◗\ ◗$

Comment: @Alice&Bob Just find Chrone! Chrone is an expert in this! +1 XD

Comment: Alice & Bob made the the right choice here because Chrone would have accidentally eaten all those free foods and may (or may not) swallow the spirit along with them, haha! Thanks, @OmegaKrypton :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the

> wordplay tag, and the hints about hidden words,

the way the puzzle works is that

> names of (alcoholic) spirits are hidden inside the names of objects in the pictures. Our goal is to find these spirits.

The hidden spirits:

> Pic 1: d**rum**
>  Pic 2: **gin**gerbread
>  Pics 3 & 4: **whis**k + **key** = **whiskey**
>  Pics 5 & 6: (Sydney) Har**bour** (Bridge) + rib**bon** = **bourbon**
>  Pics 7 & 8: **pi**llow + **sco**ne = **pisco**; snow**sho**es (credit @Tom) + **chu**tney = **shochu**

Comment: Very good start! Everything is correct so far.

Comment: Images 7 & 8 maybe [rot13](https://www.rot13.com/) Gjvar ynprq fabjfubrf & Pehzcrg

Comment: @Tom rot13(V qba’g guvax jvar vf pbafvqrerq n fcvevg.) Also, that is not a crumpet; crumpets are more pancake-like but apart from that they’re very similar and both originated in the UK. This solution also doesn’t work because it contradicts the addendum (If I understand your solution correctly).

Comment: I think you may have forgotten to remove the "Partial Answer" header.

Comment: @Chrone whoops, thanks for pointing that out haha

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer:

Hint II:

> The blank is to be filled with "tree/ cherry/ whiskey (Credits @Volatility)", but where is location three? Is the Sydney Bridge the igloo? So, the postcard?

Comment: Location three means the third location and If you look at the group of images in a normal (English) reading order (left-to-right, top-to-bottom), that would be the kitchen. “A crazy Igloo junk” is a cryptic crossword-ish clue. rot13(Gur nantenz bs “Vtybb whax” vf “ybbx va wht” juvpu vf jurer gur juvfx pna or sbhaq va. Gur oynax vf fvzcyl gb or svyyrq jvgu “xrl”. Pbzcyrgr gur juvf(x) jvgu gur (arnerfg) xrl naq lbh tbg “juvfxrl”.) The whole Hint II is solely made for that particular spirit.